# Replace placeholders inside word document using Javascript or macro

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, ms-word

I have the needings to modify a word document dynamically using a template and some input data that will come from a database or an excel file that is used like a database.
I never used macro and visual basic, so I need to understand it first if I want to modify the actual scrip.t

I've analyzed the document and this is the macro that is used to generate automatically the documents

```vb
Sub CreaDocumento()
'
' CreaDocumento Macro
'
'

    Dim recordStart As Long
    Dim recordEnd As Long
    
    Dim percorsoDB As String
    Dim NomeFileDB As String
    Dim NomeFile As String
    Dim percorsoFile As String
    
    Dim NumRecord As Long
    Dim KK As Long
    Dim NomeForn As String
    Dim CodPdv As Variant
    
    
    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Seleziona il file da aprire"
        .InitialFileName = ThisDocument.Path 'DA MODIFICARE
        On Error Resume Next
        .Filters.Add "Origini Dati", "*.xlsx", 2
        On Error Resume Next
        .FilterIndex = 2
        If .Show = -1 Then

            For Each selezione In .SelectedItems
                percorsoDB = selezione
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox "Operazione annullata!", vbInformation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Right(percorsoDB, 5) <> ".xlsx" Then
            MsgBox "Formato file non corretto! Operazione annullata!", vbInformation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    a = 0
    
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
        percorsoDB, ConfirmConversions:= _
        False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:= _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & percorsoDB & ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Databa" _
        , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `DATI$`", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
        wdMergeSubTypeAccess
    
    c = 0
    
    Dim objexcel As Object
    Dim objworkbook As Object
    Dim objworksheet As Object
    
    Set objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    objexcel.Visible = True
    
    Set objworkbook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open(percorsoDB)
    Set objworksheet = objworkbook.Worksheets("DATI")
    
    NomeFileDB = objworkbook.Name
    
    NumRecord = objworkbook.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(objworksheet.Range("B:B"))
    If NumRecord > 1 Then
        For KK = 2 To NumRecord
            NomeForn = objworksheet.Cells(KK, 2)
            CodPdv = objworksheet.Cells(KK, 8)
            percorsoFile = ThisDocument.Path
            NomeFile = "AUTOR.RIFATT.DIRETTO." & NomeForn & "." & CodPdv & ".docx"
            With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                With .DataSource
                    .FirstRecord = KK - 1
                    .LastRecord = KK - 1
                End With
                .Execute Pause:=False
            End With
            ChangeFileOpenDirectory percorsoFile & "\"
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=NomeFile, FileFormat:= _
                wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
                :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
                :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
                SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=14
            ActiveWindow.Close
        
        Next KK
    End If
    
    objexcel.Application.Workbooks("DB.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set objworksheet = Nothing
    Set objworkbook = Nothing
    Set objexcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've noticed that the macro will stop working if the document is modified and I'm thinking to replace the macro with a dedicated javascript tool. I want to use nodejs, and I've found that microsoft have released a javascript api, but I'm not sure if I can achive the same thing. Is there a better way than macro to replace the fields inside the word document and generate the needed documents automatically?

Comment: There are plenty of options, depending on your own preferences and knowledge. You can surely create documents by using javascript. Everything boils down to your skillset and the product code base :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov I've opted for an office JS add-in that will replace VB macro and will do the same thing using the api that office will provide :)